# Kubernetes expose TCP service using NGINX Ingress Controller got 400 error code

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I want to expose the service which is a proxy server that is built based on [dperson/torproxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/dperson/torproxy) that works well inside the k8s cluster but got failed when trying to expose it to the public/outside of the cluster.

I have installed the [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) using helm by specifying TCP on `values.yml`:

```
...
tcp:
  8080: "default/proxy-server:8080"
  6379: "default/redis:6379"
```

which perfectly created the config map, tag and other requirements as described in [the official doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/). (also tried to expose Redis service which just works fine).

Here is the error when trying to access via telnet command:

```
$ telnet example.com 8080
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx ...
Connected to example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid header received from client
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: close

Invalid header received from client.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Accessing the service through port-forwarding to localhost also works fine. So I think there might be any missing configuration that I need to pass to the NGINX ingress controller?